# Decidability of equations in True Arithmetic

Tags: computability, peano-axioms

Is the validity of equations (with variables) in True Arithmetic decidable?
In [1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1815098/decidability-of-quantifier-free-formulae-in-peano-and-true-arithmetic), Andreas Blass argues that validity of *negated* equations is undecidable by sketching a reduction of Hilbert's 10th problem. But what about pure equations (or, equivalently, universally quantified equations)?