# Is arithmetic with a $\exists\forall$ induction schema decidable?

Tags: logic, quantifiers, decidability

First a word on notation. Let an uppercase Latin letter except $S$ be a free variable. Let a lowercase Latin vowel be a variable bound a universal quantifier. Let a lowercase Latin consonant be a variable bound by a non-universal quantifier. Let $\text{FV}(\varphi)$ denote the free variables of $\varphi$ and let $\chi[M := \psi]$ be a capture avoiding substitution replacing $M$ with $\psi$ in $\chi$.

[Robinson arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robinson_arithmetic) replaces Peano arithmetic's axiom schema of induction with the following non-schematic axiom.

$$ Y = 0 \lor \exists x \mathop. Sx = Y $$

We can rephrase this as

$$ \forall a \mathop. \exists x \mathop. a=0 \lor Sx = a $$

I'm wondering what happens if we allow the full axiom schema of induction shown below, but constrain $\varphi$ to be an $\exists\forall$ sentence. I chose this constraint specifically to make the *only zero has no predecessor* claim inexpressible.

$$ (\varphi[X:=0] \land \forall a \mathop. \varphi[X:=a] \to \varphi[X:=Sa]) \to \varphi[X:= Sa]$$

This amounts to imposing the following constraints.

$$ \text{FV}(\varphi) \subset \{X\} $$
$$ \varphi \;\; \text{must be of the form} \;\; \exists x_1 \cdots x_n \mathop. \forall a_1 \cdots a_m \mathop. \psi \;\; \text{where $\psi$ is quantifier-free} $$

I'm pretty sure that this construction doesn't run afoul of [this result](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1815111) because I'm not adding in all the true facts about the standard model of arithmetic. Unless I'm missing something, at least the *fact that all non-zero numbers have a predecessor* cannot be proven.

---

Post-script

I'm really not sure about what to do with parameters in $\varphi$, discussed [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3441667) among other places. I'm *assuming* that I need to prohibit them but I'm not really sure.

Comment: No consistent extension of Robinson's Q is decidable.

Comment: @AndreasBlass I tried to construct this thing so that "only $0$ having a predecessor" was not a theorem ... making that part of Robinson arithmetic inexpressible was how I picked $\exists \forall$ as the "shape" of an allowed wff in my induction schema. It's possible (and likely) that I failed and this thing is an extension of Robinson arithmetic after all, but that's what I was trying to avoid.

Comment: That should say "only 0 lacking a predecessor", but it's too late to edit it.

Comment: You're right, I didn't read carefully enough. It might be worth noting that Shoenfield's book "Mathematical Logic" proves the essential undecidability of a theory that he calls N.  This N is similar to Robinson's Q but doesn't prove that only $0$ lacks a predecessor. So it might be of some use for your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This theory isn't decidable, since a subtheory of a finitely axiomatizable undecidable theory is never decidable. Specifically, your theory is a subtheory of (for example) the finitely axiomatizable theory $I\Sigma_2$. Let $\theta$ be a one-sentence axiomatization of $I\Sigma_2$, and $\varphi$ an arbitrary sentence in the language of arithmetic; then $\theta\rightarrow\varphi$ is provable from your theory iff $\varphi$ is provable from $I\Sigma_2$. Since $I\Sigma_2$ is undecidable, this means your theory is undecidable as well.

Note that there's a crucial subtlety here: when we say "$X$ is decidable" we need to **specify a language**. For example, the empty set is  decidable as a theory in the empty language but is **not** decidable as a theory in the language of arithmetic by exactly the same argument above. (The same applies to "$X$ is complete.") By default, when we ask whether a theory is decidable we are speaking relative to *the smallest language containing all symbols actually used in that theory*, so we would indeed say "The empty theory is decidable" despite the technical ambiguity.

Note, however, that there is a difference between decidability and having a decidable extension; similarly with completeness. So we can ask:

> Does your theory have a consistent decidable extension?

(Note that from a consistent decidable extension we can build a consistent decidable *complete* extension, by a greedy algorithm.) This is really the right version of the "Godelian question." I suspect the answer is **no** here, but I don't immediately see the proof.

Comment: Thanks. I'm assuming $I\Sigma_2$ means Peano Arithmetic but with the induction scheme limited to things at position $\Sigma_2$ in the [arithmetical hierarchy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetical_hierarchy) (does $\Sigma_2$ mean the same thing as $\Sigma_2^0$?) ... Why is $I\Sigma_2$ finitely axiomatizable (or is that better asked as another question?) ... also, unless I'm missing something, why isn't the theory I sketched in the question $I\Sigma_2$ ?

Comment: @GregoryNisbet Yes, that's what it is. Note that there is a difference between "$\exists\forall$" and "$\Sigma_2$" - the latter permits *bounded quantifiers* for free. Also, we allow parameters. $I\Sigma_2$ is finitely axiomatizable because of the existence of **universal $\Sigma_2$ formulas**, or - equivalently - of a $\Sigma_2$ truth predicate for $\Sigma_2$ formulas. The details are a bit messy for a comment thread; if you're interested, you could ask a separate question about it (strangely enough I don't think this one has been asked here before).