# Why is $I\Sigma_2$ (arithmetic with $\Sigma_2$ induction) finitely axiomatizable?

Tags: logic

According to [this comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4131337/is-arithmetic-with-a-exists-forall-induction-schema-decidable/4131375?noredirect=1#comment8546015_4131375) on [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4131375) to [this question I asked an hour ago](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4131337), there exist universal $\Sigma_2$ sentences.

$\Sigma_2$ sentences are part of the [arithmetical hierarchy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetical_hierarchy). They allow bound or unbound quantifiers, one quantifier alternation, and with $\exists$ as the outermost quantifier. In addition, well-formed formulas in $\Sigma_2$ are allowed to contain parameters.

It seems really surprising to me that *universal $\Sigma_2$ formulas exist*. I'm not completely sure what a universal formula means; and the definition of universal formula seems to differ from the [*definition presented here*](https://modeltheory.fandom.com/wiki/Universal_theory).

At the moment I'm thinking about a *universal formula* in the context of $I\Sigma_2$ as simply being a formula $\varphi$ such that "$I\varphi$", where the induction non-schema trivially ranges over $\varphi$ alone, proves the same theorems as $I\Sigma_2$. I'm curious what the actual definition is though since this definition is really weird and bakes in the language of arithmetic $\{0, 1, +, *\}$ and other stuff about arithmetic that feels really incidental.

So, my question is threefold:

- Why do universal $\Sigma_2$ sentences exist?
- Is the proof of their existence constructive or nonconstructive?
- What is the *real* definition of a universal $\Sigma_2$ sentence?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no connection with the notion of a universal theory. Roughly, a **($2$-variable) universal $\Gamma$-formula** for some syntactic class $\Gamma$ is a $2$-variable formula $\varphi(x,y)$ such that:

- $\varphi\in \Gamma$, and
- for each $1$-variable formula $\psi(x)\in\Gamma$ there is some $c$ such that $\psi(x)\equiv \varphi(x,c)$.

Think by analogy of a **universal Turing machine**, or - if you're familiar with descriptive set theory - of the notion of a [universal set for a pointclass](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3125059/28111). The existence of a universal $\Sigma_n$ formula, for each $n$, is **totally constructive and explicit**. For example:

- "The $x$th Turing machine halts on input $y$" is universal $\Sigma_1$, and is basically a rephrasing of the halting problem..
- "For every $z$ the $x$th Turing machine halts on input $\langle y,z\rangle$" (with $\langle \cdot,\cdot\rangle$ being an appropriate pairing function) is universal $\Sigma_2$, and is basically a rephrasing of the *totality problem* (which Turing machines halt on all inputs?) which has Turing degree ${\bf 0''}$ - "the halting problem's halting problem."

And so on. (As usual we express statements about Turing machines and halting in the language of arithmetic via [Kleene's $T$ predicate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kleene%27s_T_predicate).)

---

The point is that we can use universal formulas to **collapse schemes**. For example, let $\eta(x,y)$ be universal $\Sigma_2$. Then the single sentence $$\forall y[\eta(0,y)\wedge\forall x(\eta(x,y)\rightarrow\eta(x+1,y))\rightarrow\forall x(\eta(x,y))]$$ expresses induction for all $1$-variable $\Sigma_2$ formulas.

Note that while I've focused on the language of *first-order arithmetic* above, we can also talk about universal $\Gamma$-formulas in other contexts. For example, in the language of second-order arithmetic (which despite the name is the setting of many interesting *first-order* theories) the existence of universal $\Pi^1_n$ formulas for each $n$ gives the finite axiomatizability of each of the theories $\Pi^1_n$-$\mathsf{CA_0}$ which appear in reverse math. And on the set-theoretic side we get, thinking in terms of the Levy hierarchy, that [(a version of) $\mathsf{KP}$ is finitely axiomatizable](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/266352/is-kripke-platek-theory-finitely-axiomatizable/266358).